# How do I require a minimum version of node.js in my script?

Tags: node.js

I just found out that a script I wrote only works on node 0.10 because it uses `readable` events.

How do I require a minimum version of node.js in my script so that users know that they need to upgrade?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In package.json:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=0.10.3" } }
```

From the [docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#engines).

**Edit, a programmatic way:**

```
var pkg = require('./pacakge'),
    semver = require('semver');

if(!semver.satisfies(process.version, pkg.engines.node)) {
  // Not sure if throw or process.exit is best.
  throw new Error('Requires a node version matching ' + pkg.engines.node);
}
```

Comment: That helps but the script probably won't be distributed with npm. I added some code that checks the node version exposed by `process.versions` as a second answer.

Comment: @hwiechers I updated my answer with how I would do it programmatically, but I understand if you accept your own answer if that's what solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to top the top of your script.

```
var versionComps = process.versions['node'].split('.');
if (parseInt(versionComps[0]) === 0 && parseInt(versionComps[1]) < 10) {
  console.log('Script requires node.js version >= 0.10');
  process.exit(1);
};
```